# When generating a corpus for latent Dirichlet allocation, does word frequency within documents matter?

Tags: text-mining

I have my set of documents and have extracted the unique words from them, including a count of the number of times each word appears in the document.  But it would seem from the documentation on the [Python library I'm using](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html), that word count within documents is immaterial, and that co-occurrence is the main thing.

Am I correct in that understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Note that LDA has the assumption that each topic, or a language model, is a multinomial distribution over all words. For a document, multiple occurrence of the same word is a draw from this multinomial distribution. So, in theory, word counts matter.

However, in terms of inference, if you use Gibbs sampling, you probably need to re-sample topic assignments for multiple occurrence. But if you use variational inference, you just do it the same across multiple occurrence.